# Arduino: serial.read within ISR

Tags: arduino

I am writing a small test program that attempts to perform a `serial.write()` followed by a serial.read() within an ISR. The code will eventually be used to prompt an external GSM shield to send an SMS on a regular basis.

```
ISR(TIMER2_OVF_vect) {

    Serial.println("AT+CMGS=\"0123456789\"");     // Tell Sim900 To prepare sms to number 01...
    while(Serial.read()!='>');                    // Wait for Sim900 to respond
    Serial.print("A text message");               // the SMS body
    Serial.write(0x1A);                           //Confirm send instruction
    Serial.write(0x0D);
    Serial.write(0x0A); 
  }
}
```

What I have found after a lot of testing is that `Serial.read()` within an ISR is not capable of reading a live serial prompt, instead it will only read any input that was buffered before the ISR was triggered.

Is there any way around this?

The only solution I have found is to place this code instead within the main `loop()`. But I want to send the SMS using a timer interrupt.

Thank you

Comment: Set a flag in the interrupt, then handle it in the loop.

Comment: You can't read from serial inside an ISR because the ISR has an interrupt priority above the serial ISR

Comment: However, I'm under the impression that read/write tasks in ISRs are bad business

Comment: @EricFossum So from a software engineering perspective, is using an interrupt to read serial just a bad practice?

Comment: @Cookie Anything that takes a long time is considered really bad practice. I don't know how long a Serial.read() takes, but I doubt it's very fast. I think it's better practice to set a flag with the interrupt and then use a function to catch the flag and do the work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem a while ago which I managed to resolve by using the Arduino [SoftwareSerial](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) library instead of the hardware based `Serial.read`.

There are some overheads associated with using SoftwareSerial, and you can only read one port at a time, so I leave it up to those with a better understanding of the Arduino platform to tell you if this is a good idea, but one of the benefits of this library is that you can use it within an ISR.

To use the SoftwareSerial library, add the following two lines of code at the top of your sketch remembering to replqce the rx_pin and tx_pin with the corresponding pin values you want to use:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(rx_pin, tx_pin);
```

Then replace the key word `Serial` throughout your sketch with `mySerial` (or whatever name you have chosen to give your SoftwareSerial instance).

An important thing to keep in mind when using SoftwareSerial is that you can only use certain pins on the Arduino so read the [documentation](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial) first.

Answer (score 1):

You need to place the code in the `loop()` but using an IF:

```
float toBeSent = interval;

loop() {
    if (millis() > toBeSent) {
        Send();
        toBeSent = milli() + interval;
    }
}
```

**interval** is your sending interval in milliseconds.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to live dangerously you could enable interrupts inside the ISR and use a flag to prevent reentry.

```
int flag=0;

ISR(TIMER2_OVF_vect) {
flag = 1
if (flag){return;}
sei();
Serial.println("AT+CMGS=\"0123456789\"");     // Tell Sim900 To prepare sms to number 01...
while(Serial.read()!='>');                    // Wait for Sim900 to respond
  Serial.print("A text message");               // the SMS body
  Serial.write(0x1A);                           //Confirm send instruction
  Serial.write(0x0D);
  Serial.write(0x0A); 
  }
  flag = 0;
}
```